# VLCメディアプレイヤーの Javascript API で、再生速度を変更する方法

Tags: javascript, html

現在、 VLC メディアプレイヤーの Web プラグインを利用して動画再生を行うページを作成しています。

そこで動画を倍速再生する必要があり、その方法として Javascript API の `vlc.input.rate` で再生速度を操作しようとしていたのですが、問題が発生しました。

解決方法をご存知の方はいらっしゃらないでしょうか。

**○問題**  
    ∟`vlc` オブジェクトが取得できない。

**○現象**  
    ∟「[VLC Wiki: Documentation:WebPlugin](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin/)」を参照として、以下のソースで再生速度を1.5倍に操作しようとしたのですが、ソース中の `vlc.input` が `undefined` となっていました。

**○ソース**

```html
<object type="application/x-vlc-plugin" id="vlc" width="640" height="360" classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" codebase="http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab">
    <param name="src" value="rtmp://s2m5qclftojb1s.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/oceans-clip.mp4" />
    <param name="video1" id="mrlVideo" value="rtmp://xxxxx.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/xxxxx.mp4" />
    <param name="volume" value="50" />
    <param name="autoplay" value="false" />
    <param name="loop" value="false" />
    <param name="fullscreen" value="false" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="toolbar" value="true" />
    <param name="windowless" value="true" />
    <embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" name="video1" autoplay="false" loop="false" width="640" height="360" target="rtmp://xxxxx.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/xxxxx.mp4"/>
</object>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var vlc = document.getElementById("vlc");
vlc.input.rate = 1.5;
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: すいません、記述内容から抜けておりました。
実際のコード上は</object>で閉じられております。

Comment: 文のフォーマットを直す時に気付きましたが、 `</object>`タグの位置がずれてませんか？

Comment: この記述でずれてないのであれば、 `<object id="vlc">` が DOM として解釈される前に `document.getElementById("vlc");` をしているので問題が発生している、ですかね？ </object> の下あたりに script をもっていくか、window.onload あたりで呼ぶか。。確認する環境が無いのでなんともいえんのですが。。

Comment: ああ、ずれてるというのはそういうことでしたか・・・・。
確かにおかしいです。
ご指摘ありがとうございます！
というわけで上記を修正したのですが、やはり状況は改善されないようです・・・。

Comment: Jquery.ready()からの呼び出しも行ってみたのですが同様の結果でした。
DOM解釈の問題ではないようです。

Comment: 確認しているブラウザはIEでしょうか?

Comment: はい、IE11で動作を確認しています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveXのVLC WebAPI使用方法ですが、VLCのインストールディレクトリにある`test.html`が参考になるかと思います。

私の環境では下記のディレクトリです。

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\sdk\activex
```

### HTML

[axvlc.cab](http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab)は既に存在せず`404 Not Found`ですので、下記の様に書き換える必要があります。
(param等は適宜書き換えてください)

```
<object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" width="640" height="360" id="vlc" events="True">
  <param name="MRL" value="" />
  <param name="ShowDisplay" value="True" />
  <param name="AutoLoop" value="False" />
  <param name="AutoPlay" value="False" />
  <param name="Volume" value="50" />
  <param name="toolbar" value="true" />
  <param name="StartTime" value="0" />
  <EMBED pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
    type="application/x-vlc-plugin"
    version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"
    width="640"
    height="360"
    toolbar="true"
    loop="false"
    text="Waiting for video"
    name="vlc">
  </EMBED>
</object>
```

### JavaScript

`getVLC()`を使用してvlcオブジェクトにアクセスできます。
(IE 10, Chromeで動作を確認)

```
function getVLC(name)
{
    if (window.document[name])
    {
        return window.document[name];
    }
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")==-1)
    {
        if (document.embeds && document.embeds[name])
            return document.embeds[name];
    }
    else // if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")!=-1)
    {
        return document.getElementById(name);
    }
}

getVLC("vlc").input.rate = 1.5;
```